# android admob doesnt show on 5.0

Tags: android, admob

I have an application where I have admob on the bottom of the relativelayout and everything working fine except android 5.0.

Here is a link where you can see teh admob height is 1 pixel.

[image]

One more thing I have copy pasted all the admob related code from my project to the new project and when I run the new project on the emulator it show the admob poerfectly on 5.0 android.
If you have any idea how to solve this please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Post your layout XML, post your code, post your logcat.

Comment: especially the layout pls

Comment: solved, the problem was the black bottom bar was front of the adview, So I have to added margin_bottom to ad view as much as the bottom bar.